# My GPO only runs the first time it is linked to the OU

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I am attempting to distribute a .msi file via GPO to Win7 machines from a Server 2008 R2 network.  I am getting a funny result.  The first time I link the GPO to a OU the program loads.  I uninstall the program and run gpupdate /force but the program will not load.  I remove the GPO link reboot the machine then add the GPO back in and it will run on the next reboot.

In my testing I have removed any other GPO to the OU.  I have also remade the GPO from scratch and only added the path to .msi in the Computer Configuration\Policies\Software Settings\Software installation.

Any ideas on how to get the program to load after the first go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly you're seeing normal behavior of Software Installation Policy.

If you manually remove the installed-software from a client computer after the GPO has applied and installed the software you will not see the software reinstall itself automatically on subsequent boots (or `gpupdate` applications).

When you remove the link to the GPO that assigns the software and subsequently re-apply the link the software *will* install.

That's just how the Software Installation Client Side Extension works. If you'd prefer different behavior you should consider using a Startup Script to perform the installation. In that script you can check for the presence of the software on each boot and, if necessary, install.

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't aware that it only ran it once.  With all the questions asking how to only have GPOs install once I thought it was supposed install it on every reboot.